# London 2012 Olympic opening ceremony live musics

Tags: live-music, performance

I hope that some guys from the live music industry could help me. At the ceremony, particularly for the industrial revolution and the NHS sections, were all the theme musics played live, particularly for the Pantomime (Industrial Revolution) and the NHS sections. Thanks very much.

Please see video here (19'20'' onwards):

So my questions are:

1. How the dummers managed to remember everyting and kept doing this again and again without a score sheet and not making any mistakes (there are so many repetitions)?
2. Was there an ear piece for everyone which told them when to start and when to finish and when to change?
3. Were all the sounds from the drums collected and broadcasted or they were included when needed?

Comment: Every single had in ears. I have audio from the feed for drummers. It was an incredible experience and very very well organised

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the music is full playback, i.e. it was pre-recorded. The few exceptions are recognizable because there are microphones (for example Evelyn Glennie's drum solo). The massed drum parts would only have been audible in the stadium. They are very repetitive, there are few changes, but it would be easy to count: everything falls into neat eight-bar phrases. All the players need to do is remember things like for example "the synths start the third time, then twice more until the rhythm change", "the guitar solo is the last time". They would have had a couple of days of rehearsals. The drum sections probably had lead drummers or conductors who made sure they were all together. It's possible that these lead drummers had in-ear monitors with a click track. Other than that there don't seem to be many in-ear monitors, the band on stage later are using wedge monitors.

Comment: Appreciate your response to my question. I just found this video which is amazing (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Bpxi3GGMF8&list=PLJFEjDF79FzLXBL6ZU_UrXpJ0FKefELC0&index=2&t=13s)! I guess there should be a pre-recorded playback with runs at the same time with fireworks, lights and all others. There should be a voice or several voices telling people when to kick in or what to do. There was a quick shot again on the drummers at the main stage later, who looked busy throughout. They must have a monitor or a voice and their drum parts should be collected...

Comment: It seems there there were a lot more in-ears than I thought.